# Improve this regex to support spaces

Tags: php, regex

I want to make this regex to support white spaces too but ( not talking about `\n` `\r` ).

```
preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$/', $text);
```

when i try to do :

```
preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_- ]+$/', $text);
```

It returns: **Compilation failed: range out of order in character class at offset 13**

Recaping everything, it should only match `a-z` & `A-Z` & `0-9` & `-` & `_` &  `space`

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use

```
preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_ -]+$/', $text);
```

otherwise (`[_- ]`) will be understood as range

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have a `-` before the space which forms a range `_-`, which is illegal since a space is lexicographically less than `_`. To solve the problem, move the `-` after the space, so you no longer form a range from the `-`.

```
preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_ -]+$/', $text);
```

Also consider using `\s` to match any whitespace character, including space, tab, newline and cariage returns.

```
preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\s-]+$/', $text);
```

PS: Be glad you didn't have a legal range, that would've been a nasty bug to identify. :)

Answer (score 1):

The `_-`  in `[a-zA-Z0-9_- ]` is interpreted as character range from `_` (*LOW LINE*, 0x5F) to   (*SPACE*, 0x20). But since `_` comes *after*  , the character range `_-`  is invalid.

Since you don’t want that character range, you either need to escape the `-` so that it’s not interpreted as character range:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_\- ]
```

Or rearrange the character so that the `-` will not be interpreted as character range indicator like when putting it just after another character range or right at the begin or the end of the character class:

```
[a-z-A-Z0-9_ ]
[a-zA-Z-0-9_ ]
[a-zA-Z0-9-_ ]
[-a-zA-Z0-9_ ]
[a-zA-Z0-9_ -]
```

Comment: While all your solutions are correct, I don't think it's wise to give people lots of options just because you can.  Additionally, the *literal hyphen if next to a range* idiom is less readable IMO, and not guaranteed to work in all regex flavors.  Just my 2¢.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the last hyphen:

```
preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\- ]+$/', $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use \S for whitespace

Documentation is found [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php)

Comment: How is that supposed to help?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your regexp string is evaluating the underscore dash space "_- " as a range. Try escaping the dash.